# How to get n element from the python list?

Tags: python

I have the following arrays:

```js
a=[1,2,3,4]
b=['car','apple','orange']
```

I'm trying to iterate through arrays using:

```js
 for first,second in zip(a,b):
        print(first,second)
```

But it prints all of the values at at time. How can I print 1st element from **a** array and 1st element from **b** array and so on?

Comment: `print(a[0], b[0])`, you need to find some basic Python tutorials.

Comment: Your code does print the elements from each array, but it stops at `3 orange` on the output because the `zip` function stops at the shortest array.

Comment: What value do you expect to be printed with `4`?

Comment: `for i in range(min(len(a), len(b))): print(a[i], b[i])` ?

Comment: the snippests don't work... that's why is recommended to make your question standalone. It s not clear what you mean with the last sentece, here my interpretation `print(f'{first}\n{second}')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [] operator to print the nth element of any array.
We can use a for loop to achieve a constant n value like this:

```
for i in range(3):
   print(a[i], b[i])
```

Replace 3 with the length of both arrays, as the length should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

You have two lists of differing lengths. Therefore, in order to access the values in pairs you could (probably should) use the *zip()* function.

If you don't want to use *zip()* then you need to start by determining the length of the shortest list then you can safely iterate over them. Something like this:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = ['car', 'apple', 'orange']

for k in range(len(min(a, b, key=len))):
  print(a[k], b[k])
```

**Output:**

```
1 car
2 apple
3 orange
```